# connect to a HTTPS url and post to it

Tags: java, https

I got a piece of [code from the internet](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1343). The code connects to a `HTTPS and displays the server response`. But the code is old, and doesn't work. Can someone please help me to modify the code so it would work.

This was the best resource i could find on the internet. I couldn't find any other.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.Security.*;
import com.sun.net.ssl.*;
import com.sun.*; 
 public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args){
        String cuki=new String();
try { 
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider()); 
URL url = new URL("https://www.sunpage.com.sg/sso/login.asp"); 
 HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true); 
connection.setDoOutput(true);

connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
connection.setFollowRedirects(true); 


String query = "UserID=" + URLEncoder.encode("williamalex@hotmail.com"); 
query += "&"; 
query += "password=" + URLEncoder.encode("password"); 
query += "&"; 
query += "UserChk=" + URLEncoder.encode("Bidder");
// This particular website I was working with, required that the referrel URL should be from this URL
// as specified the previousURL. If you do not have such requirement you may omit it.
query += "&"; 
query += "PreviousURL=" + URLEncoder.encode("https://www.sunpage.com.sg/sso/login.asp"); 


//connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","it"); 
//connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/cfm, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, ///"); 
//connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip"); 


connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length",String.valueOf (query.length())); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www- form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98; DigExt)"); 


// open up the output stream of the connection 
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() ); 


// write out the data 
int queryLength = query.length(); 
output.writeBytes( query ); 
//output.close();


System.out.println("Resp Code:"+connection.getResponseCode()); 
System.out.println("Resp Message:"+ connection.getResponseMessage()); 


// get ready to read the response from the cgi script 
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( connection.getInputStream() ); 


// read in each character until end-of-stream is detected 
for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() ) 
    System.out.print( (char)c ); 
input.close(); 
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{ 
System.out.println( "Something bad just happened." ); 
System.out.println( e ); 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
}
}
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? If there's an exception, can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: The only code on the internet that demonstrates how to establish an https connection does not work? Hmmm....

Comment: I have never used the core Java HttpClient library. If you can use other libraries apache foundation have many projects that have HttpClient implementations. E.g. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

Comment: In the "Related" sidebar on this very question I see plenty of existing questions that are directly on point and have code that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
public void postData() throws Exception {


 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.xyz.com");

 List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

 list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","ABC");

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

 HttpResponse r = client.execute(httppost);

}
```

Comment: I get a NULLPOINTER exception at `        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
` How can i solve this ?

Comment: try to see if your "httppost" which is your object reference variable of HttpPost is initialized or not..........