# POST a XML file content to a HTTPS url

Tags: java, xml, post, https

I want to send a `xml file` through `POST` request to a `HTTPS` server.

I think i have to read the content of the `XML` file and save it to a `String`, then send `POST` it to the server.

Sorry, but i don't have any code to demonstrate my workings. Can someone help me to do a Sample code or tutorial to start with this task ?

Note : I am using `Java`

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect to a HTTPS url and post to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844413/connect-to-a-https-url-and-post-to-it)

Comment: And I'm sure there are many more questions like this.  Read through the 'Related' list of this question

Answer (score 0):

Using java, You can open this XML file in READ mode and start reading and printing contents in browser.

Comment: well, i actually want to send the XML over a HTTPS url. And i need to know how i could do this ?

Comment: write that file on server first and try to read it...sending on server means writing file onto a server.